# radio button hide and show div jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a radio button with two possible values yes or no.
I would like when user press yes a div will be appeared and when no
hide the div.

My code is but it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                   $(document).ready(function() {
                   $("div.desc").hide();
                   $("input[name$='pain']").click(function() {
                   var test = $(this).val();
                   $("div.desc").hide();
                  $("#" + test).show();
                    });
                  });
               </script>

         <div id="fieldsetInner">
               <fieldset class="rightInner">
               <legend>pain</legend>
               <label for="pain" class="label2">do you feel pain ; </label>
               <input name="pain" type="radio" value="yes" id="yes" checked="checked"/> Yes  &nbsp;
               <input name="pain" type="radio" value="no"/> No

               <div id="yes" class="desc">
                <label for="pain-feature1-morph" class="label2">Morph : </label>
               </div>
          </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing the Close tag </fieldset> in your code so please apply this and check it again

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
$("input#yes").click(function() {
    $("div.desc").show();
});
$("input#no").click(function() {
    $("div.desc").show();
});
```

Comment: I suppose in input no we have to call hide function.
Unfortunately something goes wrong with my code.

It's the same to have span instead of div 
and in the script to write span.desc ?

Comment: thanks  a lot the problem I have with your code it was that I insert it in head .

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you

```
   <input name="pain" type="radio" value="yes" id="yes"/> Yes
    <input name="pain" type="radio" value="no" id="no" /> No


    $('input:radio[name=pain]').click(function() {
         if ($('#yes').attr('checked')) {
             $('.desc').show();
           } else if ($('#no').attr('checked')) {
             $('.desc').hide();
          }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a duplicate `id` in your HTML, both the div you're trying to show and the 'yes' radio button have the id 'yes'. Ids should be unique in the document.

Once you've fixed your HTML, this should work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='pain']").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        if ($("div#" + test).length > 0) $("div#" + test).show();
    })
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/mSLeA/