# jquery - showing div based on radio button checked?

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

First of all, I searched here for the past hour to see if I found an answer to my question before I posted, but you're my last hope! I found a piece of code that nearly works as I want it, but not quite.

- I need to get rid of the fade-in and fade-out.
- I need the script to check onload which radio button is checked and show the correct div.

Here is my code:

```
 <input type="radio" name="d_method" class="c_email"/>Email   
 <input name="d_method" type="radio" class="c_collection"/>Colletion 
 <input name="d_method" type="radio" class="c_post"/>Post

 <div id="c_email" style="display:none;">
   email textbox
 </div>
 <div id="c_collection" style="display:none;">
   collection textbox
 </div>
 <div id="c_post" style="display:none;">
   post textbox
 </div>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
 $(':radio').change(function() {
     var itemSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('class');
     $('div').stop().fadeOut(function() {
         $(itemSelector).fadeIn();
     });
 });
```

Comment: What not working in your script

Comment: radio buttons should hold a value... than you use `.prop()` ... bla bla bla and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8121577/448232 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4108027/448232.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $(':radio').click(function() {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeIn().siblings('div').hide();
    })
    .filter(':checked').click();//trigger the click event
});​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/H8VVP/1/